SNOWFLAKE.CORTEX Image Embedding
We are trying to create a vector SNOWFLAKE.CORTEX that embeds an image or video in snowflakes, but the steps in the snowflake documents are not available.
Could you provide instructions for creating an image similar to text?
Text embedding - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/embed_text-snowflake-cortex
We are trying to create a vector SNOWFLAKE.CORTEX that embeds an image
